# Drupal Question: How can I set the number of Characters that appear for the title in the Latest forum column?

Tags: drupal

I am trying to figure out how to make my forum titles a certain number of characters on the main Forum page. Here is the link ----> http://www.womenshealthcaretopics.com/Moms-Blog/forum
For example, Instead of just saying "How do i...", I would like it to say "How do I edit my forum". If I can't get the entire title in there, thats fine. Just a little more to gain interest is ideal. Thank you ahead of time for your help!

I'm new to Drupal so the simplest explanation would go a long way. (If there is a simple explanation :-))

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Administer › Site configuration > Advanced Forum and change the "Number of characters to display for the topic title" setting.